# Export CSV from tables

Tags: export, list-manipulation, csv-format

I am reading my csv which looks like:

float,float,float,integer,boolean

I read it with:

```
table = Take[Import["~/myfile.csv"]];
x = table[[All, 1]];
y = table[[All, 2]];
z = table[[All, 3]];
time = table[[All, 4]];
bool = table[[All, 5]];
```

Then I do some job with x,y,z and I need to export it back to csv. But I dont know how to get the table to export.

Comment: Put it in a list like so: `list={x, y, z, time, bool};` and then `Export["newfile.csv",list,"CSV"]`

Comment: it puts every table into one row. I need it as columns seperated by comma

Comment: I what @Pickett suggests is basically correct, but I also that you get an output table more to your liking by using `list = Transpose @ {x, y, z, time, bool};`. That will put things back into columns.

Comment: BTW, `{x, y, z, time, bool} = Transpose[table];` is an easy way to extract column data.

Comment: It works, thank you :) If you write it as an answer I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Transpose.html).

```
table = Take[Import["~/myfile.csv"]];
{x, y, z, time, bool} = Transpose[table];
(* do stuff *)
output = Transpose[{x, y, z, time, bool}];
Export["newfile.csv", output, "CSV"]
```